# WinRT and DLLs: What exactly am I allowed to use?

Tags: c#, dll, windows-runtime, json.net, html-agility-pack

It's not all together clear to me, so I am hoping someone here knows the answer.  I am using the C# Json.Net and the C# HtmlAgilityPack both built from sources for "Any CPU". I've noticed that both of these include using directives that reference assemblies that don't seem to be available in Metro yet they both build fine.

If I reference them, does this mean my app will thunk to unmanaged code?

What exactly causes thunking to unmanged code?

Why are DLLs allowed to reference assemblies that are not available to WinRT and my app is not?

Will this fail the windows store approval process?

What are the general rules for DLLs I include with my app that I need to worry about?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

When developing apps that target WinRT, the app should only use the API's available in Windows 8 WinRT. The API's are defined in WinMD files. If the app used the desktop API's, then it will be rejected during the Windows store approval process.

Imagine this scenaio. You developed a WinRT app that uses .NET DLL's from desktop mode (client profile). The app is deployed in Windows store and user downloads it on ARM tablet. The application will crash as it does not have the desktop (client) .NET DLL's on the ARM devices.

so this brings us to the question on what .NET classes we can use while developing apps for WinRT. The article http://kishore1021.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/what-is-portable-class-library-project-in-visual-studio-2012-net-4-5/ lists the .NET classes available for WinRT application development.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change all open source projects dependencies to target WinRT. See if some methods / classes in WinRT are missing so the code does not compile. Try to find the alternative methods/classes.

Such as List.FindAll(), change to Linq Where()

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should point out that the libraries I am using DO compile.  So does that mean I can use them even though they reference assemblies not available in WinRT?